# QtConcurrent in QT for Symbian

Tags: qt, qt4, qtconcurrent

I have a question about supporting of QtConcurrent in Qt for Symbian. I use Qt 4.6.2 but I'dont understant how to use QtConcurrent. All works fine on Wice platform in the same version of QT, but doesn't work on Symbian. How to enable QtConcurrent, QFuture, QFutureWatcher?

Big thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QtConcurrent and QFuture are not implemented in Qt for Symbian yet: see Qt bug about that: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-5182